# New table from two table with max(timestamp) - Bigquery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables where the combination of retailer and id are the one common between the two. I need to create a new table for all retailer + id combination from the first table and respective data for those from the second table that has the latest timestamp

The first table will have only one record for each retailer, id combination but the second table will have multiple records for each retailer, id combination based on the time it was scraped, I need to create a new table with the latest timestamp data for each combination

input table 1:

[image]

input table 2:

[image]

output table:

[image]

Comment: sounds very basic/simple! have you tried anything and have some specific issue that we can help with?

Comment: also, please check [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we do not need to do OCR against your images :o)

Answer (score 1):

This is basically aggregation and `join`:

```
select *
from table1 t1 left join
     (select t2.retailer, max(timestamp) as max_timestamp
      from table2 t2
      group by t2.retailer
     ) t2
     on using (retailer);
```

If you wanted the entire most recent *row*, you can use a variant of this:

```
select *
from table1 t1 left join
     (select ( array_agg(t2 order by timestamp desc limit 1) )[safe_ordinal(1)].*
      from table2 t2
      group by t2.retailer
     ) t2
     on using (retailer);
```